# Make floating window tab widths wider in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, tabs

How can I make the floating window tabs wider/static width in Notepad++ (version 5.9.6.2)?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fkuvf.png]

Answer (score 1):

Open up **Settings** > **Preferences**, go to the **General** tab and find the **Tab Bar** box.

If **Reduce** is checked, unchecking it will make your tabs wider (but also taller).

Checking **Show close button on each tab** will also widen your tabs. How much use you get out of this option depends on why you want the wider tabs, of course.

I'm not aware of any way to make all tabs a static width.

As far as I know, Notepad++'s configuration info is located<sup>1</sup> in

```
C:\Users\[you]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml
```

I don't know for sure what everything in that file means, but I did just take a quick look through it and didn't see any tab width options. (There is a `TabSetting` value, but that's for converting tab characters into space characters.) I also checked `stylers.xml` in the same directory, and got nothing.

<sup>1: [How to migrate Notepad++ settings?](https://superuser.com/questions/137481/how-to-migrate-notepad-settings)</sup>

Comment: Tried that, the reduce only worked on the file tabs, not the floating window tabs.

Comment: Well, you can't say the good Lord knew you tried that method @jco

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've misunderstood what you meant by "floating window tab," then. I can open the "Find result" window, but I don't see any tabs other than the regular file tabs when I do. How do you get to the tab(s) you're asking about?

Comment: I opened two tabs and drug them together to make a floating window, the other one I'm using right now is "workspace" but any would work that float.

Comment: Also, good joke ;-)